# Unable to extract download link using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch the download CSV file link from this: https://patents.google.com/?assignee=intel

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://patents.google.com/?assignee=intel")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('a', class_='style-scope search-results')
soup.find_all('a', class_='style-scope')
```

But last 2 lines are returning empty array. What am I missing here?

Even this is not returning anything:

```
soup.find(id="resultsLayout")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the elements are being generated by javascript. You can use selenium to get the whole page source.

Here's an edited version of your code using selenium.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://patents.google.com/?assignee=intel')
page = browser.page_source
browser.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('a', class_='style-scope search-results')
soup.find_all('a', class_='style-scope')
```

Let me know if you need clarifications. Thanks!